# Connecting flight with long layover in Korea

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, airport-terminals

I am a Philippine Passport holder.

I will travel to Brazil passing Incheon, South Korea, to arrive on March 29 at 8 pm in the airport and onward to Brazil on March 30 at 10:30 am.

I plan to sleep in the airport and not go sightseeing. And there is a transit hotel inside terminal 1. Do I still need a Visa?

Answer (score 3):

Philippine nationals don't need a visa to transit through Incheon airside for connecting flights within 24 hours.

Philippine nationals are eligible for the free transit tour program, which allows you to exit the airport on one of several guided tours during your layover. You can [book one of these tours in advance](https://www.airport.kr/ap/en/trn/trnTourMain.do), or on arrival at the [green transit tour desk](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_8_5.jsp) in the international transit arrivals area just before immigration. Based on your itinerary, though, you probably don't have time to join one before your onward flight.